# Работа с прокси в библиотеке telegraf.js

Tags: node.js, telegram-bot

Не работают прокси в телеграфе, выдает ошибку

```
Launch failed
Error: 401: Unauthorized
    at C:\Users\admin\Documents\parawa\botele\anyvoice-telebot\node_modules\telegraf\core\network\client.js:281:17
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)
```

Я использую открытые прокси sock5, вот код:

```
import Telegraf, {  Extra, Markup } from 'telegraf';
import { SocksProxyAgent } from 'socks-proxy-agent';

const agent = new SocksProxyAgent("socks://109.31.103.113:25193");
const options = {
    telegram: {           // Telegram options
        agent: agent,        // https.Agent instance, allows custom proxy, certificate, keep alive, etc.
        webhookReply: false  // Reply via webhook
    }
};
const bot = new Telegraf(process.env.BOT_TOKEN, options);
bot.start();
```

В чем проблема? Без прокси под впн работает.

Answer (score 0):

> Error: 401: Unauthorized

Что-то не так с TOKEN, где-то в нем ошибка закралась